# pgfplots: How to specify custom tick and label at specified value on an axis

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to specify a custom tick with a custom label at a sp

```
\begin{axis}[       
symbolic y coords={<{Critical point} at 2.138  ???>},
]
\addplot+[samples=100,domain=-2:2] {x^2};
\end{axis}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `extra y ticks` to specify the ticks you want to customize and `extra y tick style` to specify their style, for example:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    extra y ticks={2.18},
    extra y tick style={
        grid=major,
        yticklabel={$P_c$},
        yticklabel style={yshift=0.7ex, anchor=east}}]
\addplot+[samples=100,domain=-2:2] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]