# Add third line of labels to axis in TikZ

Tags: pgfplots, ticks, axis

I have a TikZ figure, where one axis is a bit overpopulated. My solution is to add further lines to the labels using

```
extra x ticks={...},
extra x tick label={...},
extra x style={tick label style={yshift=...}},
```

However, I can only add a second line with this method. I know an option is simply to add a node with some text in the desired position, but I would like to know if there is a solution using the axis options. My code which does not work:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Define parameters
\newcommand*{\DELTAb}{0.25}%
\newcommand*{\DELTAa}{0.4}%     
\pgfmathsetmacro{\LOWB}{1-\DELTAb}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\HIGHB}{1+\DELTAb}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\LOWA}{1-\DELTAa}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\HIGHA}{1+\DELTAa}%    
\newcommand*{\ALPHA}{0.5}%      
\begin{axis}[
% Define axis properties
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
enlargelimits=false, 
clip=false,
ytick=\empty,%{1},
ymin=0,
%ymax=1,
xtick={0, \LOWB, 1, \HIGHB},
xticklabels={$0$, $w-\Delta_b$, $w$, $w+\Delta_b$},
extra x ticks={0.9},
extra x tick labels={$w - \Delta_b(\delta_{b,2} - \delta_{b,1})$},
extra x tick style={tick label style={yshift=-4mm}},
extra x ticks={\LOWA, \HIGHA},
extra x tick labels={$w-\delta_b$, $w+\delta_b$},
extra x tick style={tick label style={yshift=-8mm}},    
xmin=0.43,
xmax=1.8,
samples=250,
domain=0.55:1.6]
% Draw functions
\addplot[name path=A,smooth,thick,mark=none] {(1/x)^(1/(1-\ALPHA))} node[right,pos=1,yshift=-0.1cm] {$f(w_i)=C{w_i}^{\frac{-\rho}{1-\rho}}$};
% Find intersections    
\path[name path=C] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0); % X axis named
\path[name path=D] (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}); % Y axis named
\path[name path=vline0] (1,0) -- (1,5); %vertical line1 in w
\path[name path=vline1] (\LOWB,0) -- (\LOWB,5); %vertical line in -delta
\path[name path=vline2] (\HIGHB,0) -- (\HIGHB,5); %vertical line in +delta
\path[name path=vline3] (\LOWA,0) -- (\LOWA,5); %vertical line in -delta
\path[name path=vline4] (\HIGHA,0) -- (\HIGHA,5); %vertical line in +delta  
\path[name intersections={of=vline0 and A,name=v0A}]; % Create intersection at average
\path[name intersections={of=vline1 and A,name=v1A}]; % Create intersection-1
\path[name intersections={of=vline2 and A,name=v2A}]; % Create intersection-3
\path[name intersections={of=vline3 and A,name=v1B}]; % Create intersection-1
\path[name intersections={of=vline4 and A,name=v2B}]; % Create intersection-3   
% Draw lines                                        
\draw[dashed,thick,gray] (v1B-1) -- (\LOWA,0);
\draw[dashed,thick,gray] (v2B-1) -- (\HIGHA,0); 
\draw[dashed,thick,gray] (v1A-1) -- (\LOWB,0);
\draw[dashed,thick,gray] (v2A-1) -- (\HIGHB,0);     
\draw[dashed,thick,gray] (1, 0) -- (v0A-1); 
% Draw averages
\path[draw,solid,red,name path=P1] (v2A-1) -- (v1A-1);
\path[name path=vline0b] (0.9,0) -- (0.9,5); %vertical line1 in w   
\path[name intersections={of=vline0b and P1,name=v0Ab}]; % Create intersection below average    
\draw[dashed,gray] (v0Ab-1-|{axis cs:0.43,0}) -- (v0Ab-1) node[left,black,pos=0] {$\lambda^{HET}_a$};
\draw[dashed,gray] (0.9,0) -- (v0Ab-1); 
\path[draw,solid,red,name path=P2] (v2B-1) -- (v1B-1);  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

So basically, you cannot have two set of `extra x ...` commands, as the last one overrides any previous one.

Comment: is rotating `xtick` labels and than have it in line an option?

Comment: @Zarko That is an option (which hasn't occur to me, thanks), and I know how to do that, but still I want to know how to add a third line. I have rather long entries and would like to try this mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one set of extra labels, and have different shifts, as in [Individual tick label style depending on position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235953/individual-tick-label-style-depending-on-position):

```
extra x ticks={0.9,\LOWA, \HIGHA},
extra x tick labels={{$w - \Delta_b(\delta_{b,2} - \delta_{b,1})$},$w-\delta_b$, $w+\delta_b$},
extra x tick style={tick label style={yshift={\ticknum == 0 ? "-4mm" : "-8mm"}}},
```

The `<comparison> ? <value1> : <value2>` is a shorthand for `ifthenelse`, you could also use the more obvious `ifthenelse(\ticknum==0,"-4mm","-8mm")`.

In the code below I also suggest a somewhat less verbose method for making that diagram, by defining a function and using a `ycomb` plot instead of calculating all those intersections.

[image: output of below code]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Define parameters
\newcommand*{\DELTAb}{0.25}%
\newcommand*{\DELTAa}{0.4}%     
\pgfmathsetmacro{\LOWB}{1-\DELTAb}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\HIGHB}{1+\DELTAb}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\LOWA}{1-\DELTAa}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\HIGHA}{1+\DELTAa}%    
\newcommand*{\ALPHA}{0.5}%      

\begin{axis}[
% Define axis properties
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
enlargelimits=false, 
clip=false,
ytick=\empty,
ymin=0,
xtick={0, \LOWB, 1, \HIGHB},
xticklabels={$0$, $w-\Delta_b$, $w$, $w+\Delta_b$},
extra x ticks={0.9,\LOWA, \HIGHA},
extra x tick labels={{$w - \Delta_b(\delta_{b,2} - \delta_{b,1})$},$w-\delta_b$, $w+\delta_b$},
extra x tick style={tick label style={yshift={ifthenelse(\ticknum==0,"-4mm","-8mm")}}},
xmin=0.43,
xmax=1.8,
samples=50,
domain=0.55:1.6,
declare function={f(\x)=(1/\x)^(1/(1-\ALPHA));}
]


% Draw functions
\addplot[name path=A,smooth,thick,mark=none] {f(x)}
node[right,yshift=-0.1cm] {$f(w_i)=C{w_i}^{\frac{-\rho}{1-\rho}}$};

\addplot [ycomb,mark=none,dashed,thick,gray,samples at={1,\LOWB,\HIGHB,\LOWA,\HIGHA}] {f(x)};

\draw [red] (\LOWA,{f(\LOWA)}) -- (\HIGHA,{f(\HIGHA)});
\draw [red,name path=A] (\LOWB,{f(\LOWB)}) -- (\HIGHB,{f(\HIGHB)});

\path [name path=B] (0.9,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (0.9,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
%
\draw [
  name intersections={of=A and B,name=I},
  thick,dashed,gray
] 
  (0.9,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (I-1) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0 |- I-1) node[left,black] {$\lambda^{HET}_a$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, nice how logical expressions embed into the commands! Regarding your simplifying suggestion, looks nice too, although it uses `pgfplots` rather than `tikz`, which I am less familiar with (reason why I did not add the `pgfplots` tag in the first place). It definitively looks neater though!

Comment: @luchonacho Your question is about manipulating axis labels for a `pgfplots` plot, which, while it might involve TikZ commands, should warrant a `pgfplots` tag, even if you're less familiar with it.